# color of Button on emulator doesnt match actual devices

Tags: android, android-studio, android-styles

I've created a button with background look as shown at picture below.
Device on left emulator right.

[image]

The device is Samsung Galaxy SIII
Emulator is Nexus 5

Button code :

This is the XML code of the button

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_main_start"

        android:text="@string/button_Start"
        android:textSize="30sp"

        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:theme="@style/buttonTheme"
        android:textAllCaps="false"

        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />


<style name="buttonTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button</item>
</style>

        <style name="button" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#FF000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">-1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.2</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>

</style>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#00CCFF"
    android:centerColor="#0000CC"
    android:endColor="#00CCFF"
    android:angle="90"/>
<padding android:left="7dp"
    android:top="7dp"
    android:right="7dp"
    android:bottom="7dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="2dip"
    android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<corners android:radius= "8.0dp" />
</shape>
```

New to Mobile development so tell me if more information is needed.

MY SOULUTION:
Not sure if this is the proper solution but I put "android:theme="@style/buttonTheme" in the manifest.xml and it worked out.

Comment: Use image as background.

Comment: Will you post your layout xml?

Comment: @HareshChhelana Thank you,But I want to understand what I did wrong.

Comment: Try removing `<item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>`

Comment: change `<style name="button" parent="android:Widget.Button">` to `<style name="button" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your layouts, you must have different layouts for different devices. Similarly check your styles, for different versions.

Update:

To test remove button theme and add android:background="@drawable/button"

Comment: Don't quite understand what your'e saying :( ...
Do I get any different layouts on default?

Comment: To test remove button theme and add android:background="@drawable/button"

Comment: This method works slightly.
The background works find but I still don't have textcolor,shadow,and all stuff I had in style.They need to be coded for each button if I wanted them.
Have any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, you are not using parent themes correctly. Check parent="android:Widget.Button" and this parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

Comment: YES!,
I didn't used themes correctly.
Not sure if this is the proper solution but I put "android:theme="@style/buttonTheme"
in the manifest.xml and it worked out.
Thank you for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Pull `<item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>` from your style and add:

```
<style name="buttonTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button</item>
    <item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/button</item>
</style>
```

to your theme.

Comment: or maybe just `<item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>`